# Как использовать Excel файл из Google Docs в PHP?

Tags: php, xls, google-docs, google-docs-api

Нужно из Google Docs с публичной ссылки брать xlsx и читать определенные параметры. Как получить сам xlsx? Если есть, покажите рабочий пример.

Comment: [Говорят](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18106727/1211184), что можно общаться с Гугл таблицей как с `.CSV`

Comment: Да, а [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23394860/1211184) говорят, что формат URL немного поменялся.

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент получение публичного файла с Google Docs не вызывает проблем.

Обычная публичная ссылка на просмотр имеет формат

```
"https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tGgG0G-bXyK_pyaLJ-zRNfHloWxHrVOsOAHofatjYiw"
```

Берем из нее параметр id и подставляем в эту ссылку

```
"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{id}/export?format=xlsx&id={id}"
```

По ней получаем искомый xlsx, который можно сохранить в файл или тут же парсить.